# Insert additional html tags before all tags like <a>

Tags: php, regex

I would like to modify html string from wysiwyg.
After saving data to database my text looks like:

```
   something bla bla
<p> something bla bla bla ba</p>
<h3 class"blabla"> bla bla bla</h3>
<p class"smtg"> another text bla bla <a href="blabla" class="blabla2">Nice url</a> </p>
<ul>
<li>lilislist</li>
<li>lilislist</li>
<li>lilislist</li>
<li>lilislist</li>
</ul>
<img src="blabla.jpg">
bleblebleblebe
<a href="blabla" class="blabla2" target="" id="notblabla">Nice url2</a>
```

Of course this is only example.
I would like to add additional paragraf(eg.`<p class="special">special text</p>`) before each `<a>` and `<img>` element. However elements `<a>` and `<img>` must keep all attributes etc.

I know that this is easy to do with jquery but I can't use JavaScript here.
It must be done by PHP.

Do you know how I can do it? Let's suppose that my string with html tags is assigned to **$DBdata**.

Comment: You should use a php based DOM parser. Try googling for it. This certainly _can_ be done using regexes, but such approach is time consuming and error prone. Use a tool that is better suited for handling such structures.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @arkascha Which php DOM parser can you me recommend? I'm reading about SimpleHtmlDom but this one probably don't have metod to insert additional tag before selected

Comment: It certainly does! The first sentence in the documentation: "A HTML DOM parser written in PHP5+ let you manipulate HTML in a very easy way"